# fontspec and \color

Tags: color, fontspec

Compiling the following example (with xelatex or lualatex), I would expect to get violet letters abc:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Verdana}

\begin{document}
\color{violet}abc
\end{document}
```

However the result are black letters. Using `\fontspec[Color=violet]{Verdana}abc`, I get violet letters as expected. However I do not know how to change color in math mode. Further it breaks automatic coloring of TikZ nodes.

Is this by design, or is it a bug (in either `xcolor` or `fontspec`). Is there a workaround? How do I change math colors?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bug in v2.1a of fontspec, sorry. V2.1b on CTAN fixes the problem.

Comment: Thank you. I should have updated TeX Live before asking here.